# Command line arguments in main

Tags: c

I've written a code that sums up integers brought in from the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int* argv[]) {
  int i, s=0;

  for (i=1;i<argc;i++) 
  s=s + *argv[i];

  printf("Sum: %d\n", s);

return 0;
}
```

The best part is, it passes the gcc compiling process, but when I actually run it and insert the numbers, the result seems I somehow breached the range of `int`.

Comment: "The best part is, it passes the gcc compiling process" -- no it does not.

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to add it, it represents sum and it `int`

Comment: You're summing pointers, not integers.

Comment: Compiling with warnings may have told you that the second argument of `main` should be `char **`...

Comment: @Jongware, it compiles as is, even with the `int * argv[]`. A simple `gcc file.c` yields no warnings even. I'm surprised this doesn't give a warning!

Comment: @Aaron: pre-edit, it did not. And I make sure to use `-Wall` on principle -- this issues a warning for the malformed `main` declaration.

Comment: I have `-Wextra` and `-Werror` as well :-). I'm just surprised that `gcc` doesn't complain. Is there any legitimate use of `main` with such a signature? I guess there might be some strange environments where `main` is not the entry point, and therefore it doesn't have to be 'special'

Comment: It does on my system: `warning: second argument of 'main' should be 'char **'`.  But I wouldn't be surprised if this is due to Apple's private tinkering with `gcc`, as mine gets identified as `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2`. I never bothered to check; maybe I have been running `clang` all along.

Comment: For a detailed discussion of the return type (and arguments permitted) to `main()`, see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336). The C standard stipulates two possible signatures (`int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and equivalents); it permits an implementation to define other signatures for `main()`. C++ is less permissive; it requires the return type to be `int` (C does not). You certainly can't just change the types of the arguments; the implementation must also support it.

Comment: there are only two valid formats for main: 1) int main(void)  2) int main( int argc, char**argv)  (although this will normally also be accepted: 3) int main() 4) int main( int argc, char*argv[])   Anything else is not correct and enabling all the warnings for the compiler will raising a warning about an invalid main declaration.

Comment: Irregardless of what type your code claims the argv array to contain, in reality, it contains pointers to strings.  so argv[x] will get a pointer to a string. This is a string from the command line.  a string char [] = "1234" cannot be directly read as a int.  rather, it must be converted, using something like: int myNum = atoi(argv[x])  This kind of line: 's=s + *argv[i];' will treat the first 4 (on a 32 bit system) 0x31323334 as a integer number, which is definitely not 1234 decimal. (which has the memory representation of: 0x000004d2)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It seems that you are compiling your code in C89 mode in which `s` is taken as `int` by default by compiler. `s` is uninitialized therefore nothing good could be expected. If fact it will invoke *undefined behavior*.</strike>

Note that `argv[i]` is of `char *` type (change your `main` signature) and you need to convert it to `int` before adding it to `s`.

Comment: but didn't I specifically do that when I declared it as `int*`?

Comment: No. It should be `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `s` initialized properly as shown below. 
Along with this the prototype of your `main()` should be as shown below inorder to get the command line arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int s =0;
  // Check for argc matches the required number of arguments */
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
  s=s + atoi(argv[i]); /* Use atoi() to convert your string to integer strtol() can also be used */

  printf("%d\n",s);
  return 0;
}
```

PS: Using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behvaior

Comment: You've missed the abuse of the signature of `main()`.

Comment: The declaration of argv is incorrect in the question as well. Although maybe that doesn't matter so much. Does `int*` convert to `char*` silently on the way into `atoi`?

Comment: I'm sick of people asking "Why the down vote?" within 30 seconds of people making a downvote. Be patient while people write their comment about why they voted. Readers shouldn't have to see those kind of comments. Please delete the "why down vote?" comment (and I will delete this comment then also)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sir you meant I needed to have the edited changes? Sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: @Gopi; He meant to correct the signature of `main`.

Comment: Your revision now includes `argc` and `argv` (an early version didn't), but you've not commented upon the misuse, merely quietly fixed it.  The chances are that `atoi()` on the arguments is what is wanted; adding `*argv[i]` would also work, adding the character values of the first character of each argument, and therefore producing a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 2<sup>nd</sup> argument of `main` should be either of type `char**` or of type `char*[]` and not `int*[]`. So, `*argv[i]` is of type `char`. Instead of getting each character, you can get each string(`argv[i]` which is of type `char*`) and then extract the number from it and assign it to a variable, say `num`. This can be done by using the `sscanf` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { //int changed to char here
  int i, s=0,num;

  for (i=1;i<argc;i++) 
      if(sscanf(argv[i],"%d",&num)) //if extraction was successful
          s=s + num;

  printf("Sum: %d\n", s);

  return 0;
}
```